# Automatically populate unique word documents with fields from Excel (Office 365 business version 1701)

Tags: vba

I need to find a way to automatically update some procedure documents (word docs) with fields from a spreadsheet:

[image]

There are 20 documents in total, so really I would like a single method where I can apply updates to all documents in one go.

All the documents are based on the same template; however, each contians an table (which logs the version history for that document). The content of this table is unique and the number of rows varies from document to document.

The first thing I though of was using a mailmerge; however, this would mean I woudl loose the unique tables from each document and would have to re add them, which would defeate the point of automating the process.

I have made the fields that I want to update in the word doc as Legacy Text Form Fields, and have found some VBA code which enables me to specify, that specific form fields should update from specific cells in my spreadsheet; however, I have to specify these for each docment individually.

This is the code I am using

"FormFields("Field1").Result =ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A2").Value"

Ideally I need a method that will work for every word doc in a given folder, identifing the related row in the spreadsheet and updating the doc accordingly. The word docs are named as the Doc ID (first column in spreadsheet).

Answer (score 0):

Add DocVariables in Word.  If you don't know how to do this, Google it.  Then, run the script below, from Excel.

```
Sub PushToWord()

Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim bkmk As Word.Bookmark
sWdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , False)
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(sWdFileName)

objWord.activedocument.variables("BrokerFirstName").Value = Range("BrokerFirstName").Value
objWord.activedocument.variables("BrokerLastName").Value = Range("BrokerLastName").Value

ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Finally, loop through all Word docs in a single folder.